# How to overlap 'table' and 'div' wrapped in another 'div' on window resize

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

I have **table** element and **div** element positioned next to each other. Both are wrapped in another div .

Her is an example :
  http://jsfiddle.net/7Ge4h/

```
<div>
    <table id="table-inside-div">
        <tr>
            <td><div>Table inside the div</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div>Table inside the div</div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <div id="div-inside-div">
        <span style="background:red">Div inside the div</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I resize the output window horizontally and the table and the div get next to each other as close as possible the div goes beneath the table but I want it to just go over the table if it was with fixed position. How can I do that?

Comment: Media query? Change the position of that class to fixed at an certain browser width?

Comment: I was thinking why not use a media tag so when the width gets to x you just don't display the table anymore? `display: none;`. [**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/7Ge4h/1/)

Comment: I'll try with the media. My way was to set the one or the other with position of 'fixed' and then align it accordingly to the right or to the left bu I gues that this would work too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

CSS

```
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    #div-inside-div {
        position: fixed;
    }
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Ge4h/8/)

Comment: I believe the OP said the other way round. You may want to change that lol. Div over table.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an id to the parent `div` and set position to `relative` then the `#div-inside-div` to `absolute`

```
#main{
    position:relative;
}

#table-inside-div{
    float:left;
    background: yellow;
    width:200px;
}

#div-inside-div{
    float:right;
    width:200px;
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yknKV/3/

Comment: You didn't put `position:absolute;` in your demo.